# react-admin, Icons disappear when collapsing menu, leaving only labels

Tags: material-design, material-ui, admin-on-rest, react-admin

As title. 
Details in images

Versions:

```
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.4.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^1.0.0",
    "ra-core": "^2.5.2",
    "react-admin": "^2.1.4",
```

**Not collapsed**

[image: Not collapsed]

**Collapsed**

[image: Collapsed]

**Root.js** of admin panel(removed few lines like setting up providers and similar resources):

```
import { Admin, Resource, fetchUtils } from 'react-admin';
import UserIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Group';
import AccountIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Payment';

const Root = () => (
  <Admin
    title="Administration"
    history={history}
    loginPage={LoginPage}
    authProvider={customAuthProvider}
    dataProvider={uploadCapableDataProvider}
    dashboard={Dashboard}
    customSagas={[formErrorSagas]}
    locale="de"
    i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
  >
    <Resource
      options={{ label: 'Kontomodelle' }}
      name="checking_account_variants"
      list={AccountVariants}
      create={AccountVariantCreate}
      edit={AccountVariantEdit}
      icon={AccountIcon}
    />
    <Resource
      options={{ label: 'Administratoren' }}
      name="admin_users"
      list={AdminUsers}
      create={AdminUsersCreate}
      edit={AdminUsersEdit}
      icon={UserIcon}
    />
  </Admin>
);
```

Is there anything else I should add there?

Im testing this on latest chrome.

**Update**

I think I found a moment when this started to appear. 
My task was to upgrade many dependencies in project and we had already `package-lock.json` alongside with `yarn.lock`. When I started I didn't want to have `package-lock.json` anymore so I just deleted it and started upgrading packages with yarn.

It's strange for me but when I revert all changes and `yarn` with `package-lock.json` and `yarn.lock` in place it works all fine, but when I `yarn` with only `yarn.lock` (no dependecy changes) - I can observe the behaviour as above. I'm sorry I'm newbie in package management, thus I don't understand why this happen.

**Pre-changes:**

```
{
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.4.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "@rails/webpacker": "3.5",
    "assert": "^1.4.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "8.2.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "connected-react-router": "^4.3.0",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "date-fns": "2.0.0-alpha.7",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.0-rc.3",
    "final-form": "^4.9.1",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "i18n-js": "3.0.9",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "json-stringify-safe": "^5.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "marked": "^0.5.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "material-ui-pickers": "^1.0.0-rc.13",
    "normalizr": "^3.3.0",
    "prettier": "^1.15.3",
    "promise-polyfill": "^8.0.0",
    "prop-types": "15.6.2",
    "query-string": "5",
    "ra-core": "^2.1.3",
    "ra-data-json-server": "^2.1.4",
    "ra-language-german": "^2.1.1",
    "ramda": "^0.25.0",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-admin": "^2.1.4",
    "react-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "react-cookie-consent": "^1.10.0",
    "react-dom": "16.4.1",
    "react-final-form": "^3.6.5",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scrollchor": "^5.1.0",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-form": "^7.4.2",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "^3.8.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.4",
    "yaml-loader": "0.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "enzyme": "3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.1.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "3.3.4",
    "eslint": "5.0.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.10.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "expect": "^23.6.0",
    "fetch-mock": "^7.2.5",
    "jest": "23.2.0",
    "jest-localstorage-mock": "^2.4.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "stylelint": "^9.9.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.2.0",
    "stylelint-declaration-use-variable": "^1.7.0",
    "stylelint-order": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.2"
  },
}
```

**Post-upgrade:**

```
{
"dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.0.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.4.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^1.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "3.5",
    "assert": "^1.4.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "8.2.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30000926",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "connected-react-router": "4.5.0",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "date-fns": "2.0.0-alpha.21",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "final-form": "^4.11.0",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "i18n-js": "3.1.0",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "json-stringify-safe": "^5.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "marked": "^0.6.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "material-ui-pickers": "^2.1.0",
    "normalizr": "^3.3.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.6",
    "prettier": "^1.15.3",
    "promise-polyfill": "^8.1.0",
    "prop-types": "15.6.2",
    "query-string": "6.2.0",
    "ra-core": "^2.5.2",
    "ra-language-german": "^2.1.1",
    "ramda": "^0.26.1",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-admin": "^2.1.4",
    "react-cookie": "^3.0.8",
    "react-cookie-consent": "^2.0.0",
    "react-dom": "16.4.1",
    "react-final-form": "^3.7.0",
    "react-redux": "5.1.1",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scrollchor": "^6.0.0",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-form": "^7.4.2",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "^3.8.0",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "yaml-loader": "0.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "enzyme": "3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.7.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "3.3.5",
    "eslint": "5.11.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.10.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.12.3",
    "expect": "^23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.2.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "stylelint": "^9.9.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.2.0",
    "stylelint-declaration-use-variable": "^1.7.0",
    "stylelint-order": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.2"
  },
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question. If you can reproduce your problem in a CodeSandbox (or similar), then also include that link.

Comment: Agreed what Ryan asks. Also, on which browser are you?